Find a general solution to a sequence
Let $a_n$ be a nonnegative real sequence, with a "recurrence" relation defined to be:
$$a_{n+1} = \beta a_n + \frac{u}{v+n}K,$$
where $\beta \in (0,1), u,v >0$ and $K>0$ are all fixed.
What I can only get at this moment is an upper bound using: $a_{n+1}\leq \beta a_n + \frac{u}{v}K$. One can solve this recurrence relation and arrive at some upper bound of $a_n$. However, I want a tighter bound on $a_n$, or even an exact general solution of $a_n$.

This is a first-order linear recurrence relation. I believe said type of equation has a general solution, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients

Thank you very much for all the helpful comments and answers!

We can simply set $b_n = a_n/\beta^n$ and recover the recurrence
$$
b_{n+1} = b_n + \frac{uK}{\beta^n(v+n)}.
$$
A telescoping sum leads to
$$
b_n = b_0 + uK \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\beta^{-k}}{v+k}
$$
which translates to $a_n$ by the equation
$$
a_n = \beta^n a_0 + uK \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\beta^{n-k}}{v+k}
$$
We can compare this to a integral to obtain an approximation
\begin{align}
a_n &\approx \beta^n \left(a_0 + uK \int_0^n \frac{\text dx}{\beta^x (v+x)}\right) \\
&\approx \beta^n (a_0 + uK \beta^v (\text{Ei}(-\log(\beta)(v+n)) - \text{Ei}(-\log(\beta)v)).
\end{align}
where we have used the exponential integral, which is known to have a divergent asymptotic series.

Starting from @Nolord solution
$$a_n = \beta^n\, a_0 + uK \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\beta^{(n-k)}}{v+k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\beta^{(n-k)}}{v+k}=\beta ^n \,\Phi \left(\frac{1}{\beta},1,v\right)-\Phi \left(\frac{1}{\beta},1,n+v\right)$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function.
